# How to search in dataframe by the list in python pandas

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe

I do have a dataframe and the list.

Dataframe:

```
sg_name sg_id
abcd    sg-123
efgh    sg-234
ijkl    sg-345
mnop    sg-654
qrst    sg-765
uvwx    sg-875
```

List is

```
prob = ['abcd','kjahgdf','qrst','kjahs','uvwx','kjhg', 'kjog', 'ijkl']
```

If the value in the prob list exists in df['sg_name'], then append the df['sg_id'] to the new list called "Only".

Expected output:

```
only = ['sg-123','sg-765','sg-875','sg-345']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, [`Series.isin`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html)

```
only = df.loc[df['sg_name'].isin(prob), 'sg_id'].tolist()
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way

```
only=df.loc[df.sg_name.str.contains(s),'sg_id'].tolist()
only
```